# How does getbyhostname() work?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ip

I am writing a basic UDP Client-Server program and wasn't getting the expected results from getbyhostname(). Here is a snippet from my code:

```
char *clientHostName = malloc(HOST_NAME_MAX);
gethostname(clientHostName, HOST_NAME_MAX);
printf("%s\n",clientHostName);
struct hostent thehost = gethostbyname(clientHostName);
printf("%ld\n",(*((unsigned long *) thehost->h_addr_list[0])));
```

So, the first print statement outputs what I expected, the name of my computer. However, I expect the second print statement to print out my IP Address. But no, it print out something like this: 4398250634. What is this that it is printing out? How do I get my IP Address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should not be using the `gethostbyname` interface. It's deprecated and cannot deal with IPv6, which is a real-world, practical show-stopper in 2012. The proper interface to use is `getaddrinfo`. Once you've used `getaddrinfo` to lookup a hostname and have it in a socket address form, you can use `getnameinfo` with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag to convert it to a printable IP-address form. This works for either IPv4 or IPv6, or for any future protocols.

As for your particular printing issue, how do you expect `%ld` to print an IP address? It prints a single number (`long`) in decimal (base 10). You could instead cast the pointer to `unsigned char *` and read 4 elements, each to be printed with `%d`, but again this is a bad approach.

Comment: Use `getnameinfo` with the `NI_NUMERICHOST` flag to convert it to a string then print it like you would any string (e.g. using `printf("ip address: %s\n", str);`)

Answer (score 3):

The functions you're calling, and the field you're examining, give you a 32-bit variable with each 8-bit octet containing on segment of your IP address. The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define HOST_NAME_MAX 1024

int main (void) {
    char *clientHostName = malloc(HOST_NAME_MAX);
    gethostname(clientHostName, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    printf("%s\n",clientHostName);
    struct hostent *thehost = gethostbyname(clientHostName);
    printf("%ld\n",(*((unsigned long *) thehost->h_addr_list[0])));
    printf("%08lx\n",(*((unsigned long *) thehost->h_addr_list[0])));
    return 0;
}
```

on my Xubuntu box gives:

```
formaldehyde
16842879
0101007f
```

and, if you break down that hex number at the end into `01`, `01`, `00` and `7f`, that's (in reverse order due to my CPU) `127.0.1.1`, one of the loopback addresses.